# MySQL: Ordering with boolean case and timestamp (and not boolean then timestamp)

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with some columns :

| Id | Active | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | 23-09-10 |
| 2 | NULL | 23-09-11 |
| 3 | FALSE | 23-09-12 |
| 4 | TRUE | 23-09-15 |
| 5 | NULL | 23-09-16 |

I want to order my results according to this priority order
If boolean is TRUE then order by boolean TRUE and timestamp, then other boolean values (false or null) and timestamp.

First time playing with order BY with CASE...

I tried :

`ORDER BY (case when active then 0 else 1 end), timestamp;`

or

`ORDER BY actif IS TRUE DESC, timestamp;`

It orders with Boolean true, then false, then Timestamp

| Id | Active | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | 23-09-10 |
| 4 | TRUE | 23-09-15 |
| 3 | FALSE | 23-09-12 |
| 2 | NULL | 23-09-11 |
| 5 | NULL | 23-09-16 |

What I want to achieve is "true and timestamp" then "FALSE|NULL and timestamp"

| Id | Active | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | 23-09-10 |
| 4 | TRUE | 23-09-15 |
| 2 | NULL | 23-09-11 |
| 3 | FALSE | 23-09-12 |
| 5 | NULL | 23-09-16 |

Comment: I tried with the following :
ORDER BY COALESCE(active,'FALSE') DESC, timestamp;
In order to consider "NULL" as FALSE.

Can someone confirm it will do the job ? (because I use few examples queries and I way not encounter some cases...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like active column is a string. You can write:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN active = 'TRUE' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

If the ordering "All TRUE then all FALSE then all NULL" is safe for you then

```
ORDER BY active = TRUE DESC, `timestamp`
```

If you want "All TRUE then all FALSE/NULL mixed" then

```
ORDER BY NULLIF(active, FALSE) DESC, `timestamp`
```

Comment: Thank you, for this solution.
I prefer the 'CASE' solution because it keeps what I was trying to achieve, but yours works perfectly too.

Comment: @zebu14 My solution does not differ from one with CASE, except the visual form.